# Wrong md5 hash values when hashing a file line by line

Tags: c++, hash, io, md5, ifstream

My program tries to hash the file *Passwords.txt* line by line. However, everytime it does this, all the hash values are incorrect.

```
void Rainbow::generateTable(string filename)
{
    //noOfLines=0;
    //bitsToRemove=0;

    ifstream myfile("Passwords.txt");

    if (myfile)
    {

        string line;

        while (getline(myfile, line))
        {
            noOfLines++;                         
        }
     }


    cout << "File is " << noOfLines << " lines long!" << endl;


    toRoundUp = log2(noOfLines);

    cout << "toRoundUp is " << toRoundUp << endl;
    bitsToRemove = ceil(toRoundUp);

    cout << "bitsToRemove is " << bitsToRemove << endl;

    //myfile.close();

    ifstream file("Passwords.txt");
    string myline;

    if (file.is_open())
    {



        while (getline(file,myline))
        {

            cout << md5(myline) << endl;


        }

    }




    displayMenu();


}
```

However, when I attempt something like this : the hash value is correct

```
cout << md5("one") << endl;
```

The contents of Passwords.txt are as follows :

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
ten
eleven
twelve
thirteen
fourteen
fifteen
sixteen
seventeen
eighteen
nineteen
twenty
```

These are the hash values output by my program :

```
945da772b285bb656550d0c2b94ef80c
9d6ec883255ab3527cd340baad797de5
e119d725f6a7b5413a61da21e7232cd5
31897146a8acc1eede32b7cbf4280f86
d97ee990314c796d0cfbedf39dc9d716
b27f9179c0570da135ec7c7f71c06692
b5e416cbaa6b63b46bf6975b2f365bfe
684349fb14f1cd243d91699a03c00b00
67ed2e62351f8e26e2ba17c30075f8be
41be321de3beb1474b2281bbbe4c8115
59bb31725256bd2af6d0b45d6372ff7a
ac573bd3385c4c0a19d5998bd16b3c0a
aae690fe1db712f89101e6665eccdb4a
93cfff3ce14123aa984447d33cd7fbe4
f35aa54743fa6bb0b8a319e55f8830ae
f516ed17f1fefe016cb3a3a398745682
f81da1a9d89b53a89fc71113ff9da7dd
aac5308f9cd346f9a11b9ff510ebd355
5178aa7f04124a2b930aa02abd9dc7f1
067636f2e9b0852519f85c2a33782b00
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: And do the `md5` take a `std::string` object as argument? There's nothing wrong with the code you show (functionally anyway), so the problem must be in the `md5` function, which you don't show. And besides the actual output, what is the *expected* output?

Comment: Stop using MD5 for anything security-relevant like passwords.

Comment: Apparently they do? It's not showing any warnings when i compile. I've even tried using md5(myline.c_str()) but to no avail

Comment: I could be misreading your code, but there seems to be things missing, reading the algo on wikipedia implies youll need some padding, and a few other calculations, also you list 'bits to remove' above, but i dont see it actually being used....http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5 edit: seeing theother comments im guessing what i mentioned is being done in the md5 function, sorry misunderstanding.

Comment: Where do the `md5` function come from? Is it one you made yourself? One you found on the Internet? Part of a system library?

Comment: Its part of my reduction function, but its not relevant. What I want to know is why I am unable to step through the file and hash each word.

Comment: It's probably that the file uses `\r\n` EOLs. The MD5 of `one\r` is `945da772b285bb656550d0c2b94ef80c`.

Comment: md5 function is from www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-md5-function

Comment: @Biffen That sounds plausible! How should one go about fixing this issue?

Comment: @JaredAaronLoo You could trim each line if you want to get rid of all whitespace, or just look for, and remove, `\r` at the end specifically. Or fix the file once and for all.

Comment: This seems to be a very confusing mix of text, is this the whole function? You declare ifstream myfile but then later in the same function declare it as a string

Comment: Misreading myfile and mystring, my bad. I clearly cant read code at 4 in the morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Biffen mentioned, creating a file with *nano* and doing so via the Ubuntu GUI causes differences in the EOLs. As such, all i need to do was discard the existing file and create an "identical" one via the Ubuntu GUI.

Comment: Or you could just use `dos2unix` on the original file.